# Arangement of html elements

Tags: html, css, z-index, absolute

I am working in a page which contains two diffirent plugins which conflict with eachother  on html. One plugin arange divs absolute. The other plugin makes a custom made dropdown list. The problem is.. that if i put the select box, in one aranged div. and there is another aranged div under it. The selectbox inside the top div will go behind the bottom div.. I want this div to go on top over the other block instead. I dont want to rearange all z indexes from bottom to top in opposite order.

I have been searching for a (css) solution to this problem. because the system is heavily depending on both plugins ( implemented on every page.) So i can't just take away one of those 2 plugins.. I hope anyone can give me a solution to this problem

This is a little example of what i mean:

```css
#div1 {
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid black:
    height:150px;
    max-height:150px;
    background-color:green;
    left: 50px;
    top:50px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:visible;
    display:block;
    z-index:1;
    color:white;
}

#div2 {
    position: relative;
    left:200px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:500px;
    z-index:999;
    color:white;
}

#div3 {
    position:absolute;
    top:250px;
    width:500px;
    left:50px;
    background-color:red;
    height:200px;
    z-index:3;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" >
Top div
    <div id="div2">This one should be on top</div>
</div>
<div id="div3">
 Bottom div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you just remove the z-index from `#div3`? When I do this, the blue `#div2` appears over the red one.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: This the result i want, but this is not the way i can do it because if i remove the z-index from div1, div2 will just go behind div3 again